# Safari Problem with jQuery live click

Tags: jquery, browser, safari

I use a live click event on items in a dropdown:

```
$('.list').live('click', function() {
var listClass = $(this).attr('title');
  $('.post').fadeOut('fast');
  $('.post.'+listClass).delay(300).fadeIn(1000);    
});
```

Seems not to work in all browsers instead of ff?

Any suggestions?

Comment: errr, sorry works ONLY in FF...

Answer (score 0):

maybe problem in

```
$('.post .'+listClass).delay(300).fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: Maybe it possible to make it with .bind() ? Or try to update jquery version

Answer (score 0):

in your css add:

```
.list{cursor:pointer}
```